# Need to return user object from find_by using email as params, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to return the entire object and its attributes to my variable but its seems to only be returning the email.

Userscontroller

```
....
def resend_act_create
  @user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])
  if @user
    @user.send_activation_email
    flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    flash[:warning] = "Could not find email in database"
    render 'account_activations/new'
  end
end
...
```

server error in views/usermailer/account_activations.html.erb

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"account_activations", :email=>"example2005@railstutorial.org", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]):
 6: Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:
 7: </p>
 8:
 9: <%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token,
10:                                                     email: @user.email) %>
```

I am not sure how to build my controller action so I can include the id for the route?

**EDIT** Add User.rb and routes

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

....
def send_activation_email
  UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
end
....
```

routes.rb

```
....
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
```

UserMailer.rb

```
def account_activation(user)
  @user = user
  mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
end
```

Comment: Check your `routes.rb`, `account_activations#edit` is probably not present.

Comment: The route exits I have first account activations email going through it this is a resend. So your saying `find_by` should return the User object like the `find` method? find_by works fine in the console.

Comment: What do your routes and user model contain?

Comment: Added those I hope that is enough I also posted the Usermailer just incase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In line 9 in your file `views/usermailer/account_activations.html.erb`

Please add the `id` as argument:

```
<%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email, id: @user.id) %>
```

Edit:

> Why do I need this?

You need it, because you use Rails magic: `resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]`
This line generates the routes for you. These routes require the `:id` as parameter. If you go to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing
You can see the generated routes for an example (you can also run `bin/rake routes` in your terminal to see your actual routes).
There you see, that the `:edit` route needs the `:id` parameter.
If you wrote your route by yourself, without using `:resources`, you could use another param than `:id` for identifying the record.

Comment: Yes sir that has got the email being sent through, may I ask why I need this line is it because I "NEED" to include it as find_by does not include it, like say for instance `@user = User.new (user_params)` would when creating and sending a activation?

Comment: Ok there must be somewhere when the user is created FOR WHEN I SEND THE FIRST account acctivation email where it doesnt need a id. The params come through as query string so I will check that for both and see.